# How to make Apache pig connect to mongodb which require authentication

Tags: mongodb, apache-pig, etl

This is the document about how to make pig read from or insert to mongodb: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Pig-Usage

But this guide did not show how to connect to mongodb which require authentication. Can someone help me out ? ;).

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. This is the guide in mongodb site: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

If you get the error:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Unable to calculate input splits: unauthorized
```

Then read these guide:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/iWRGA_HKQDM
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/wKTPri2rnSk/BCdaOgCAWNUJ
```

This is my worked script:

```
mongo_data = LOAD 'mongodb://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/test.test_1?authSource=admin' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader(...);
```